# memory wastage on pop() in queue

Tags: c++, memory-management, queue

i want to ask is memory deallocated when queue.pop() is called ?
because in stacks we just increment or decrement the pointer but memory is still  not deallocated.

The question is :WAP to Print last n lines of a big log file.
    i am saving the lines in queue and then popping lines when count >n.

is it a good codeing practice?
if not what can be done to deallocate memory?

what i coded is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void lastN(char *fileName, int N)
{
   queue<string> q;
   int count=0;
   string line;
   ifstream mf(fileName);
   if(mf.is_open())
   {
      while(!mf.eof())
      {
         getline(mf,line);
         count++;
         q.push(line);
         if(count>N)q.pop();
      }
      mf.close();
   }
   else cout<<"cannot open file\n";
   count=1;
   while(q.size())
   {
      printf("line no %2d :: ",count++);
      cout<<q.front()<<endl;
      q.pop();
   }
   cout<<endl;
}

int main(void )
{
   char *fileName="file.txt";
   ofstream mf(fileName);
   if(mf.is_open())
   {
      mf<<"line 0";
      mf<<"line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\n\n\n";
      mf.close();
   }
   else cout<<"cannot create file\n";
   lastN(fileName,5);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `queue` is holding `string` objects by value, so calling `pop` will destroy the string and release memory associated with it.

Comment: thankyou. 
you said "queue is holding string objects by value".
do you mean if queue holds pointers to the objects then it won't be deallocated?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If the queue held raw pointers, then the memory would not be released. But using smart pointers would free memory too. `std::queue<std::shared_ptr<string>>` In your case, that's an unnecessary overhead though.